# How to store multiple records in to a single id?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, oracle

Here's my doubt.. If we go to a retailer, we will purchase a list of groceries and he will come up with a bill with single Purchase id. if he in future inquired about that particular Purchase id, then we can get will the list of groceries.

Please help me "how to write that SQL query".?

thanks in advance :)

Comment: You have not provided any details at all about your current database structure so no one could provide you with an answer. Try looking up one to many relationships

Answer (score 1):

SELECT * FROM dbo.Purchase where PurchaseId = 1234

Answer (score 1):

SELECT * FROM `purchase` WHERE `purchase_id`='xxxxxxxx'

Answer (score 0):

Given the information given in OP here is what i can suggest :)

SELECT * FROM PurchaseTable Where PurchaseId = 1

Though i would strongly recommend you to go thru some SQL bookor http://www.w3schools.com/sql/ to quicky grasp the basic of sql

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, You want to create a Program where you can inquire by an ID, in the table, let there be a unique ID for every sale i.e SALE_ID different from the ITEM_ID so that One SALE_ID can have Different ITEM_IDs. The SALE_ID can be an Auto_generated Number following a Sequence every time a customer visits. Then select like the others Have Suggested Above:

```
select * from MytableName where SALE_ID = '0012';
```

This will return all the records that were Purchased By the Customer i.e

```
SALE_ID    ITEM_ID  ITEM_NAME   ITEM_PRICE
0012       001      Cabbage     200.00
0012       002      Spinach     100.00
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Standard master-detail model:

Table Purchase (purchase_id, purchase_time, ...)

Table Purchase_Item (purchase_item_id, purchase_id, item_id)

Table Item (item_id, item_desc, ...)

Your SQL:

```
select i.item_desc 
from purchase_item pi join item i on pi.item_id = i.item_id
where pi.purchase_id = <a purchase id>
```